# Attack Rolls Before Damage

Tags: dnd-5e, attack-roll

As a newcomer to DnD, I am a bit confused about the attack rolls.

Say I am playing a rogue with Sneak Attack, and an offhanded shortsword (shortsword mainhand)

So I first roll an attack roll to determine the hit, and if I get a roll+mod equal or higher than the target AC, I attack.

I roll 2d6+3 and then a 2d6.

My question is, do I have to roll an attack roll before each 1d6? Or is one attack roll suffices?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You make an attack roll for each attack, regardless of how much damage the attack deals. You also need to know that you can only use your Sneak Attack once per turn.

So you make one attack roll for your first attack, which deals 2d6+3 if it hits, assuming you've fulfilled the conditions for your Sneak Attack. Then you make another attack roll for your second attack, which deals 1d6 if you used your Sneak Attack on the first attack, or 2d6 if you didn't use your Sneak Attack on the first attack and you've fulfilled the conditions for Sneak Attack.